# How do I simulate flip of biased coin?

Tags: python, random, probability, coin-flipping

In unbiased coin flip H or T occurs 50% of times.

But I want to simulate coin which gives H  with probability 'p' and T with probability '(1-p)'.

something like this:

```
def flip(p):
   '''this function return H with probability p'''
   # do something
   return result

>> [flip(0.8) for i in xrange(10)]
[H,H,T,H,H,H,T,H,H,H]
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`random.random()` returns a *uniformly distributed* pseudo-random floating point number in the range [0, 1). This number is less than a given number `p` in the range [0,1) with probability `p`. Thus:

```
def flip(p):
    return 'H' if random.random() < p else 'T'
```

Some experiments:

```
>>> N = 100
>>> flips = [flip(0.2) for i in xrange(N)]
>>> float(flips.count('H'))/N
0.17999999999999999  # Approximately 20% of the coins are heads

>>> N = 10000
>>> flips = [flip(0.2) for i in xrange(N)]
>>> float(flips.count('H'))/N
0.20549999999999999  # Better approximation
```

Answer (score 11):

Do you want the "bias" to be based in symmetric distribuition? Or maybe exponential distribution? Gaussian anyone?

Well, here are all the methods, extracted from random documentation itself.

First, an example of triangular distribution:

```
print random.triangular(0, 1, 0.7)
```

> **`random.triangular(low, high, mode)`**:
>
> Return a random floating point number `N` such that `low <= N < high` and
>   with the specified mode between those
>   bounds. The `low` and `high` bounds
>   default to *zero* and *one*. The `mode`
>   argument defaults to the midpoint
>   between the bounds, giving a symmetric
>   distribution.
>
> **`random.betavariate(alpha, beta)`**:
>
> Beta distribution. Conditions on the parameters are `alpha > 0` and 
>   `beta > 0`. Returned values range between `0` and `1`.
>
> **`random.expovariate(lambd)`**:
>
> Exponential distribution. `lambd` is `1.0`
>   divided by the desired mean. It should
>   be *nonzero*. (The parameter would be
>   called “*`lambda`*”, but that is a
>   reserved word in Python.) Returned
>   values range from `0` to *positive
>   infinity* if `lambd` is positive, and
>   from *negative infinity* to `0` if `lambd`
>   is negative.
>
> **`random.gammavariate(alpha, beta)`**:
>
> Gamma distribution. (Not the gamma
>   function!) Conditions on the
>   parameters are `alpha > 0` and `beta > 0`.
>
> **`random.gauss(mu, sigma)`**:
>
> Gaussian distribution. `mu` is the mean, and `sigma` is the standard
>   deviation. This is slightly faster
>   than the `normalvariate()` function
>   defined below.
>
> **`random.lognormvariate(mu, sigma)`**:
>
> Log normal distribution. If you take
>   the natural logarithm of this
>   distribution, you’ll get a normal
>   distribution with mean `mu` and standard
>   deviation `sigma`. `mu` can have any
>   value, and `sigma` must be greater than
>   *zero*.
>
> **`random.normalvariate(mu, sigma)`**:
>
> Normal distribution. `mu` is the mean,
>   and `sigma` is the standard deviation.
>
> **`random.vonmisesvariate(mu, kappa)`**:
>
> `mu` is the mean angle, expressed in
>   radians between `0` and `2*pi`, and `kappa`
>   is the concentration parameter, which
>   must be greater than or equal to *zero*.
>   If `kappa` is equal to *zero*, this
>   distribution reduces to a uniform
>   random angle over the range `0` to `2*pi`.
>
> **`random.paretovariate(alpha)`**:
>
> Pareto distribution. `alpha` is the
>   shape parameter.
>
> **`random.weibullvariate(alpha, beta)`**
>
> Weibull distribution. `alpha` is the
>   scale parameter and `beta` is the shape
>   parameter.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
import numpy as np
n, p = 1, .33  # n = coins flipped, p = prob of success
s = np.random.binomial(n, p, 100)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import random
def flip(p):
    return (random.random() < p)
```

That returns a boolean which you can then use to choose H or T (or choose between any two values) you want. You could also include the choice in the method:

```
def flip(p):
    if random.random() < p:
        return 'H'
    else:
        return 'T'
```

but it'd be less generally useful that way.

Answer (score 2):

One can sample from the `X ~ Bernoulli(p)`  distribution `nsamples` times using `sympy` too:

```
from sympy.stats import Bernoulli, sample_iter
list(sample_iter(Bernoulli('X', 0.8), numsamples=10)) # p = 0.8 and nsamples=10
# [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Return `'H'` or `'T'` instead using

```
def flip(p, n):
    return list(map(lambda x: 'H' if x==1 else 'T', sample_iter(Bernoulli('X', p), numsamples=n)))

print(flip(0.8, 10)) # p = 0.8 and nsamples=10
# ['H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H']
```

Answer (score 0):

- Import a random number between 0 - 1 (you can use randrange function)
- If the number is above (1-p), return tails.
- Else, return heads

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def flip():
    return ["H" if random.randint(0,3) <= 2 else "T" for i in range(10)]
```

Right now probability of Head is 75% and tails is 25% (0,1,2 are all Heads and only 3 is Tails) . By using random.randint() you could have any probability of bias while still maintaining randomness.