# Python Genetic Algorithm "Natural" Selection

Tags: python

How can I perform selection (i.e. deletion of elements) in an array that tends towards lower numbers.

If I have an array of fitnesses sorted lowest to highest, how can I use random number generation that tends towards the smaller numbers to delete those elements at random.

```
pop_sorted_by_fitness = [1, 4, 10, 330]
```

I want to randomly delete one of those smaller elements, where it's most of the time 1, sometimes 4, and rarely 10, with almost never 330. How can I achieve this sort of algorithm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I simulate biased die in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479236/how-do-i-simulate-biased-die-in-python)

Comment: That's slightly the point it's supposed to favor survival of the "fittest" but still uses RNG to select an array index.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the comment was a bit snarky. Still, a search for *Python biased random* yields quite a few hits.

Comment: @Zavax: Please see my edit for an updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making use of exponential distribution for sampling your indexes using [numpy.random.exponential](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html)

```
import numpy as np 

s = [1, 4, 10, 330] 
limit = len(s)
scale = 10**int(np.log10(limit))
index = int(np.random.exponential()*scale)%limit
```

Test it

```
In [37]: sorted([int(np.random.exponential()*scale)%limit for _ in xrange(20)]) 
Out[37]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
```