# Efficiently generating a large array of biased coin flips

Tags: python, performance, numpy, random

I am looking for a high-performance Python solution to the following problem:

> Flip a biased coin n times so that the probability of heads (=1) is
>   equal to a given probability p. n is in the millions.

The naive Python implementation is obvious, but I suspect there can be a very efficient `numpy`-based solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I simulate flip of biased coin in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477237/how-do-i-simulate-flip-of-biased-coin-in-python)

Comment: Do you have any preference with the distribution? Uniform, binomial, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the NumPy built-in [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) -

```
np.random.choice([1,0],n,p=[p,1-p])
```

Let's verify -

```
In [120]: p = 0.8

In [121]: n = 100000

In [122]: (np.random.choice([1,0],n,p=[p,1-p])==1).mean()
Out[122]: 0.80003999999999997
```

Looks pretty efficient too -

```
In [123]: %timeit np.random.choice([1,0],n,p=[p,1-p])
100 loops, best of 3: 4 ms per loop
```