# Wondering how to effectively code coin flipper

Tags: python

Alright I was trying to code a coin flipper and I was wondering if there was a way to print if the output is heads or tails, 1 being heads and 2 being tails, I'm just not sure how to do it:

```py
import random

min = 1
max = 2
print("Flipping the coin")
print(random.randint(1, 2))
```

Comment: Sorry the code is weirdly formatted by the way, I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477237/how-do-i-simulate-flip-of-biased-coin-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional statements `if else` as:

```
import random
mini = 1
maxi = 2
print("Flipping the coin")
randOut = random.randint(mini, maxi)
if randOut == 1:
    print("Heads")
else:
    print("Tails")
```

Comment: Also, note to avoid keywords like `min`, `max`, etc. for object names.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way would be to use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).
That can be used on a 1. `dict` or a sequence like a  2. `tuple` (a `list` would also work), depending on how important is to you the number-to-text relationship (e.g. 1 -> Head).

1. with `dict()`:

```
import random

coin_outcome = {1: 'Head', 2: 'Tail'}
print("Flipping the coin")

coin_values = list(coin_outcomes.keys())
outcome = random.choice(coin_values)
print(coin_outcome[outcome])
```

2. with `tuple()`:

```
import random

coin_outcome = 'Head', 'Tail'
print("Flipping the coin")
outcome = random.choice(coin_outcome)
print(outcome)
```

---

You can rework it in a number of different ways that do avoid `random.choice()`, but this would mean hardcoding a number of assumptions.

For example, if you were to use `random.randint()` to get the key of the `coin_outcome` dictionary (as in 1.) you should make sure that the result of `random.randint()` **is** a valid key, and you cannot use say `10` and `20` without adding extra logic to handle this.

Comment: Method 2 is the simple way to do this.

Comment: They are two different abstractions. It depends on what is valued more. Method 2 abstracts away the number information we do not really care about. Method 1 explicits the key/value relationship, which may be useful in a more rich context.

Comment: Agreed, but for a coin toss it doesn't make any sense to select an integer and then convert that to a string if all you want to do is display it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use conditions to check the output. Heres a one liner code after importing `random`:

```
print("Flipping the coin\n"+("Heads" if random.choice([0, 1]) else "Tails"))
```

This is `ternary` expression.

or just select randomly between Heads and Tails:

```
print("Flipping the coin\n"+random.choice(["Tails", "Heads"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close. However, you haven't set conditions to do `print("Head")` or `print("Tail")`. Here is my solution:

```py
from random import randint

def flip_coin():
    coin_result = randint(1, 2)

    if coin_result == 1:
        return "Head"
    elif coin_result == 2:
        return "Tail"

result = flip_coin()
print(result)
```